# Can OSGi install/deploy bundles hosted on a URL?

Tags: java, url, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I'm wondering if I can configure an OSGi container like [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) (or any other popular ones) to download bundles (.BNDs) from a remote repository hosted on another machine, via any networking mechanism out there (RMI, HTTP, URLClassLoader, etc.)?

Ideally, I'd be able to deploy new versions of my bundles to this remote repo at any time, and somehow have that trigger the OSGi container "downloading" (installing/deploying) the remote bundles and hot-deploying them over older versions of the same bundle.

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OSGi has an API for managing OSGi frameworks on the BundleContext that every bundle activator receives. This API allows you to install/update a bundle via URL or InputStream.

Since this is a standardized API there have been lots of people making bundles that provide a policy around this deployment process. The archetypical one is Apache FileInstall, it watches a directory and automatically installs every bundle found in this directory and uninstall the bundle when it is gone. This works well with for example dropbox. It also supports configuring via the the Configuration Admin service. On the other hand of the spectrum you find Apache Ace which provides a remote management system.

To find the best solution, try to enlist the requirements you have. One or two systems or 1 million? Local or remote over slow lines?

One thing is for sure, you will find some project or provider being able to provide you with an OSGi bundle that implements your desired management policy.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Kriens (+1) - I think I like the Apache FileInstall solution. But which way is it: do I install the OSGi container and FileInstall on the same server, and configure FileInstall to monitor/watch a remote URL directory, and to deploy bundles dropped in that remote directory to the local OSGi container? Or do I set up FileInstall on one server, and configure it to deploy bundles to an OSGi container on a remote server? Thanks again!

Comment: FileInstall is installed as a bundle into the OSGi Framework. So it's on the same "server". It monitors a filesystem directory. In order for the bundles to come from somewhere remote, you need to use it with something like Dropbox, or BitTorrent Sync, or NFS, etc.

Comment: FileInstall has pretty good documentation: https://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html

Answer (score 0):

We use Apache Felix and maintain [an OBR repository](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-osgi-bundle-repository.html). Once set up you can deploy new versions from the OSGi shell. This does require you to manually log in and enter the command, for example `deploy com.example.foo`.

Alternatively you can install directly from urls, like `install http://example.com/bundles/bundle.jar`.

Your last requirement (auto deploy) is trickier. You could perhaps enable a remote shell on your OSGi container and as part of your build push the commands via telnet.

Comment: Thanks @merlijn (+1) - however I'm a bit confused. At first you mention that it is possible to install a bundle directly from a URL, but then you go on to say that an auto-deploy is "trickier". How are these 2 concepts different (install & auto-deploy)? Wouldn't installing the bundle deploy it as well? Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood that part of the question. Deploying a new bundle in our setup requires 2 steps: 1. Installing it to the obr repository. 2. Logging into the OSGi container & running the deploy command. We have not yet automated the second step, but it is not a pressing issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at the provisioning of Karaf at [documentation for provisioning](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/provisioning.html). 
Your able to deploy bundles either with maven urls, http or file references. Or you might deploy your set of bundles either as a feature definition (which loads all required and used bundles from a maven repo) or by deploying a kar file.